# repositories of skinned android AVDs that I can use

Tags: android

I would like to test my apps in skinned android AVDs (Samsung, HTC etc.), are there any repositories that I can download them?

Answer (score 0):

[You can find HTC skins from the below link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=783763)